# Android texture clearing in libgdx from vm

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm developing a game using **libgdx** in android. I dispose all the textures I use when the game ends (win-lose-restart) but my vm is not cleared. I tried

```
gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
```

I dispose all textures, world, objects, etc. But vm size is the same. Due to this problem I get **OutOfMemoryException** after playing a few levels.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a snippet of code that shows how you load and dispose of textures.  Also, what evidence do you have that its textures using up your memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What libgdx APIs are you using to load textures?  By default libgdx will manage texture memory so that it can, for example, reload textures into video RAM if your app gets suspended.
See the badlogic blog post about context loss here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073

What this means is that you need to tell libgdx to release the Texture, not just directly tell OpenGL to release the texture.  See [Texture.dispose()](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html#dispose%28%29).

Comment: issue fixed on 21 of oct ... also i disposed the texture as u said...thank you for your responce